# django queryset that counts occurrences of sub string in field

Tags: django, count, django-queryset

I have a model called Animal that contains a field called `text` that starts with the animal name followed by optional text e.g. cat - grey long hair

```
    class Animal:
        text = models.TextField()
```

Some examples of animals include:

```
animal1 = Animal()
animal1.text = "cat - grey long hair cat."
animal1.save()
animal2 = Animal()
animal2.text = "dog - black short hair dog."
animal2.save()
animal3 = Animal()
animal3.text = "non descriptive animal"
animal3.save()
```

I want to count the occurrences of `text` that start with `cat`, `dog` or `fish` and return that count per animal category. I assume something like this wold work:

```
    queryset = models.Animal.objects.all()
    animal_summary = (
        queryset
        .annotate(
                cats=Count(
                    Case(
                        When(text__startswith="cats", then=1),
                        default=0,
                        output_field=IntegerField(),
                    )
                )
            )
        .annotate(
                dogs=Count(
                    Case(
                        When(text__startswith="dogs", then=1),
                        default=0,
                        output_field=IntegerField(),
                    )
                )
            )
        .annotate(
                fish=Count(
                    Case(
                        When(text__startswith="fish", then=1),
                        default=0,
                        output_field=IntegerField(),
                    )
                )
            )
        .values('cats', 'dogs', 'fish')
    )

    return {"animal_count": animal_summary}
```

But it appears to count the number of entries irrespective of the sub-string.

Comment: Could you provide example set of `Animal` instances and expected results? It is hard to understand how you define sub-string.

Comment: Added. In short the first part of the `text` contains the animal type (if provided).

Comment: @Ajax posted my solution with aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

I can offer an option with [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/). I wrote the lines into my model and counted the ones that matched.

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q

    queryset = models.Animal.objects.all()

    animal_summary = queryset.aggregate(
        cat=Count('pk', filter=Q(text__startswith='cat')),
        dog=Count('pk', filter=Q(text__startswith='dog')),
        non=Count('pk', filter=Q(text__startswith='non')),
    )
```

Input:

```
<QuerySet [<books: cat - grey long hair cat.>, <books: dog - black short hair dog.>, <books: non descriptive animal>, <books: cat>, <books: cat 33>]>
```

Output:

```
{'cat': 3, 'dog': 1, 'non': 1}
```